# How to quickly change the editing language in Outlook

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've got English as my default editing language in Outlook 2013.

However, I often reply to messages in two other languages (Spanish and Catalan).  The language auto-detection does not work well for Catalan (indeed, it never detects Catalan; it confuses Catalan with Spanish).

Is there any quick way (preferably via Shortcut) to change the editing language?  I'm looking for a shortcut I can use before right before typing in Catalan because having to go through **Review**->**Language**->**Set Proofing Language** each time I reply to a catalan message is pretty slow.

Comment: It's strange I tried with English US as language to target. I assumed the language code for English US in the macro was right, I did not double-check that.  Did you try it with the code in the original post (related to style "Normal") or with the code in the variation that appears in one the comments?  Indeed, I tried with both and none works, but I'm asking to see where I should start looking.

Comment: I used the code from the original article, unmodified, and it worked without a problem.  If it's not working for you, you'll have to be more specific...  Did you modify the code at all, or use it as-is?  If you debug and step through the code one line at a time, does it go though all lines without error?  What base language is your Windows install, and what additional languages do you have installed?

Comment: I used as-is.  OK, I'll try debugging it. My UI language for both Windows 7 Professional Ultimate and Office 2013 is English US, and the dictionaries I see listed with an spell-checker in the Language dialog are Catalan, English (United States), Spanish (Spain), and Spanish (Spain, Traditional Sort).

Comment: As-is, that codes switches between EnglishUS and EnglishUK, if you don't have the EnglishUK dictionary available, that could be why it's not working for you as-is(?) :)

Comment: I was only trying to run macro SetLangEngUS(), which does not have any dependency on EnglishUK, does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added `language` to my quick access toolbar, so in my case it's just pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to change the language.

[image]

Comment: I would also like to add, that adding "set proofing language" removes one step in outloook 2016 - direct language change instead of dropdown to change and then change.

Answer (score 0):

If you **Pop Out** to compose your email in separate window then you have option to set the proofing language via Review -> Language -> Set Proofing Language
[image]

IMHO this is not available from Outlook Home toolbar.